# Import Contact Using Webservice

Tags: web-services, rightnow-crm, oracle-service-cloud

I have External Application where all the contacts are stored, where all the CRUD operation will happen in External Application, we have to replicate same in RightNow frequently, we have exposed the Web Service in External Application, I am new to Web service regarding RightNow perspective, so I am not aware where to write code to Pull all the Contact from external webserver in RightNow. it would be great help if any one provide document or reference for this.

Comment: If your external system is the system of record, then you should really push the data from it to OSvC since it will be aware of when records change and can syndicate active contact data to service cloud.  If you pull data, you can get stale data moved to the cloud that isn't needed, and you won't have the most up-to-date data from your SoR.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, this can be easily done in RightNow in two ways-

1. Manually: If this is one time work and u can do it manually then use the RightNow Import Wizard. Get all your contacts exported in the specific CSV format and then use the wizard to upload all records in one go.
2. Automation: If this "On The Go" functionality then you can use the RightNow SOAP/REST services to create the contact whenever it is getting created/updated in the third party System. For this you can write the scripts to trigger on the events of your third party system. Below is the document link. http://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/servicecs_gs/CXSVC/api-contacts.html

Hope that helps!!

Thanks, 
Abhishek